# Digital Signature Certificate set issuer name

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, x509certificate

By using java x509certificate i am generating a p12 certificate. After digitally signing a certificate its displaying Subject and Issuer as same. Can any one please help me in setting Subject as my name and issuer as company name.

P12 file its self has issuer and subject as same.

### [image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Below is my code for generating the certificate

```
package com.dynamic;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen;
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;
public class Dynamic { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{           
            Dynamic di=new Dynamic();
            di.createPFXFile();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
public boolean createPFXFile() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException, NoSuchProviderException
    {
        boolean flag=false;
        try {
            X509Certificate cert=null;
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            CertAndKeyGen gen = new CertAndKeyGen("RSA","SHA1WithRSA");
            gen.generate(2048);
            Key key=gen.getPrivateKey();
            System.out.println("private key" + key);             
            cert=gen.getSelfCertificate(new X500Name("name","ccc","ddd","eee"), (long)365*24*3600);           
            X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[1];
            chain[0]=cert;
            System.out.println("chain[0] :"+chain[0]);
            keyStore.setKeyEntry("private", key, "password".toCharArray(), chain); 
            keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream("D:/"+uid+".p12"), "password".toCharArray()); 
            return flag=true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Dynamic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return flag;
    }  
}
```

Comment: You should at least post a code sample showing what you already tried

Comment: <offtopic>Can you tell, what is the tool shown on screenshots?</offtopic>

Comment: CryptoGuy its not a tool.

Comment: CryptoGuy its not a tool. These are digital signature properties. 
In a PDF file right click on Digital Signature, show signature properties, show signer's certificate will show above images.

Comment: JCS I updated post with code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a self signed certificate hence the issue. To fix , first create a CA certificate (which can be self signed) and then use the CA to sign your certificate.